# Backbone model saving while initialized with dynamic url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone model which is shown below

```
define([], function(){
    var instaceUrl;
    var PatientModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function() {
            return instanceUrl;
        },
        initialize: function(options) {
            instanceUrl = options.instanceUrl;
        },
        defaults: {
            "person": "",
            "identifiers":""
        }
    });
    console.log('Patient model');
    return PatientModel;
});
```

When I try to  save patient model `patientModel.save`, an extra `instanceUrl` attribute is added in the request payload

```
var patientModel = new PatientModel({instanceUrl: '/patient'});
...
...
patientModel.set("identifiers", identifiers);
patientModel.set("person", uuid);
patientDetails = patientModel.toJSON();
patientModel.save(patientDetails, {
    beforeSend : sendAuthentication,
    success : function(model, response, options) {
        uuid = response.uuid;
    },
    error : function() {
        alert('failed');
    }
});
```

The model sends the following payload

```
{
    "instanceUrl": "/patient", // why is it added ?
    "person": "c014068c-824d-4346-84f0-895eb3ec6af7",
    "identifiers": [
        {
            "preferred": true,
            "location": "f15bc055-765a-4996-a207-ec4945972f33",
            "identifier": "saks9639",
            "identifierType": "866aedab-8a37-4b15-95d3-2b775fc0caac"
        }
    ]
}
```

Required payload for REST API call to succeed is

```
{
    "person": "c014068c-824d-4346-84f0-895eb3ec6af7",
    "identifiers": [
        {
            "preferred": true,
            "location": "f15bc055-765a-4996-a207-ec4945972f33",
            "identifier": "saks9639",
            "identifierType": "866aedab-8a37-4b15-95d3-2b775fc0caac"
        }
    ]
}
```

How to avoid `patientModel` considering `instanceUrl` as model attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method signature for a [model constructor/initialize method](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) is

> **constructor / initialize** new Model([attributes], [options])

where the first object passed will be added as attributes. You pass `instanceUrl` in that first hash, it is considered an attribute. See this Fiddle for a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/GADW7/

Use a second object to declare your options<sup>1</sup> :

```
var PatientModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return this.instanceUrl;
    },
    initialize: function(attrs, options) {
        this.instanceUrl = options.instanceUrl;
    },
    defaults: {
        "person": "",
        "identifiers":""
    }
});
```

and you would instantiate it as

```
var patientModel = new PatientModel({}, {instanceUrl: '/patient'});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/GADW7/1/

---

<sup>1</sup> : Note that I set `instanceUrl` as a member of the instance, going around with a global variable, even restricted to your module, is bound to cause distress down the line